# How to connect to remote msmq

Tags: vb6, msmq

I am unable to connect to remote msmq using the path name "computername\queue" I am getting error 
"The queue path name specified is invalid. 
I am using VB6

```
        Dim oQInfo   As MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo

        'Initialize the MSMQQueueInfo object.
        Set oQInfo = New MSMQQueueInfo

        oQInfo.PathName = "machine\acknakq"
        oQInfo.Open(MQ_SEND_ACCESS, MQ_DENY_NONE)
```

Comment: Try "\\machine\acknakq".

Comment: Its giving the same error.